# Gaussian filtering image with a cut-off value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, imagefilter

I have some data basically surrounded by 0 value and I would like to apply a Gaussian filter just to the no-zero values masking the zero ones.

This is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

data = np.zeros((100, 100))

for i in range(25, 76, 1):
    for j in range(25, 76, 1):
        data[i, j] = random.random()

data2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(data, sigma=5.0)

fig1 = plt.figure("data")
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
cf1 = ax.contourf(data)
fig1.colorbar(cf1)

fig1 = plt.figure("data2")
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
cf1 = ax.contourf(data2)
fig1.colorbar(cf1)
```

Sorry I don't know why but I couldn't upload the results of the MWE.

The MWE produces a 100x100 array with no-zero values in a sub-square 50x50 located in the centre with position [25:75, 25:75].

When I apply the filter the number of no-zero values increase with position [5:96, 5:96].

What I want it's to mask in some way the zeros values and not apply the filter there, the filter have to be applied just in the 50x50 sub-square.

I tried to use numpy masked array but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Do you wan to endure the 0s remain 0, or do you want the 0s to not influence the result of the filtering at all?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I want they don't influence the result of the filtering at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gaussian filtering is a local weighted averaging. If you want to adapt the weights such that certain pixels (those outside the selected area) are not used to compute the average for other pixels, you need to use normalized convolution:

```
( (f . m) * g ) / ( m * g )
```

where `f` is the image, `m` is the mask with 0 value for pixels to not be used, `g` is the Gaussian kernel, and `*` is the convolution.

Using your code it would be implemented as:

```
data = np.zeros((100, 100))
mask = np.zeros((100, 100))

for i in range(25, 76, 1):
    for j in range(25, 76, 1):
        data[i, j] = random.random()
        mask[i, j] = 1

data2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(data * mask, sigma=5.0)
data2 /= ndimage.gaussian_filter(mask, sigma=5.0)
```

This will make is so that each output pixel contains a weighted average of only pixels that have a 1 in the mask image. However, zero pixels will still get a value. You now need to mask those:

```
data2[np.logical_not(mask)] = 0
```